# Why is my code failing to compile with "unexpected type" and "cannot find symbol"?

Tags: java

I keep getting errors in the method that I created:

> unexpected type
>   required: class
>   found   : value
>
> cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : class radius
>   location: class Question2

How can I fix this?

```
public class Question2
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    java.util.Scanner keyboardReader = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int x = keyboardReader.nextInt();
    int y = keyboardReader.nextInt();
    int radius = keyboardReader.nextInt();
    DrawMeACircle(x,y,radius);
  }
  public static void DrawMeACircle(int posX, int posY, int radius)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
      {
        if (((i-posX)(i-posX) + (j-posY)(j-posY)) == (radius)(radius))
        {
          System.out.print("#");
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.print("-");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Java math doesn't work like that. If you want to multiply two things, use the asterisk `*`.

Answer (score 4):

Parenthesis are not used for multiplication in Java as they are in mathematics. Use the `*` operator.

```
if (((i - posX) * (i - posX) + (j - posY) * (j - posY)) == (radius) * (radius)) {
```

Read: [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to use multiplicate operator *

check:

`if ( ( (i-posX)*(i-posX) + (j-posY)*(j-posY) ) == (radius*radius) )`